# If inside foreach not working as expected in Laravel

Tags: laravel, if-statement

My if is not displaying as expected in Laravel.

This is in the model:

```
    public function getTags()
{
    $tags = [];
    foreach (Config::get('products.tags') as $tag) {
        if ($this->$tag)
            $tags[] = $this->getLabel($tag);
    }
    if ($this->extra_tag)
        $tags[] = $this->extra_tag;

    return $tags;
}
```

And this in the view:

```
    @foreach($product->getTags() as $tag)
        @if($this->$tag='bespoke shape')
            <div class="tag-purple">
        @else
            <div class="tag-grey">
        @endif
        {{$tag}}</div>
    @endforeach
```

I would expect to see the tag 'bespoke shape' to have purple background and other tags to have grey background. Unfortunately, they all have purple background. The names of the tags, however, are displayed correctly.

Do you have any ideas of what I can do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this->tag='bespoke shape'`

This is not how you compare, this is how you assign values. Use two or three equals to signs instead: `$tag == 'bespoke shape'`

Comment: I've tried that before and when I do, I get this error: Undefined property: Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine::$Bespoke Shape (View:

Comment: Uhm yeah, this is also not how you access properties, I have updated my answer...

Comment: Now that I think it about it more thoroughly, your whole code is messed up with wrong property accesses. `$this` should probably not be available in the view.

Comment: I am not only sure what `if ($this->$tag)` is supposed to check for in your model, and what `$this->extra_tag` is. You will most likely want to drop `$this` (wherever possible) and stick to the local scope of the model. Please clarify.

Comment: Thank you, I've rewritten it based on your suggestions and the right answer is `@if($tag=='Bespoke Shape')`. If you amend your answer, I can approve it. Thank you!

Comment: @BlueberryPie Thank you, I am glad you solved your issue.